# Angular Testing using Karma-

Tags: angular, service, jasmine, components, karma-runner

I am testing an Angular component and my component depends on a service, so my component's constructor has the service injected logically.  On `ngOnInit`, the service is being called in several places.

The issue I am having is that I need to test part of the component and only want to mock a small part of the service.  After mocking, I realised that lots of code that is in `ngOnInit` depends on the service, so this results in me replicating loads of code in the MockService so that i can make `ngOnInit` work and I can instantiate the component correctly.  But at the same it is a lot of replication.

I don't want to mock everything that is in that service, only the part I need to in the it() function.  How do I get round this?

Is there a way I can still create my component for testing, inject a mock service but on the it() overrides whatever I need to?

I don't want to create a MockService by extending the OriginalService as i want to isolate the component completely.

Thank you.

Comment: Instead of mocking everything, you could use a spy and let the injection do the rest for you. Have a look at 

https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/mocks-and-spies/#_mock_by_using_a_real_instance_with_spy

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking, then yes this is doable.  I have put together a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-q-53543380?file=app%2Fmy.component.spec.ts) to show you one possible way of approaching this.  In the stackblitz is a simple component that depends on SomeService.

As you can see in the `my.component.spec.ts` file, I am using a spy to override only the part of SomeService that is needed for each spec ('it' function).

Hopefully you can use this as a pattern and modify for your particular implementation.